# Android: mapping hostname to IP on windows 10 using DNS?

Tags: android, windows, dns, ip-address, server-name

The following works without problem in create a LAN:

```
PC: Windows 10 mobile hotspot.
    Web server is running on windows 10.
Android: Connect android to the hotspot.

http://192.168.137.1/foo.html
```

How to access the page using a server name such as

```
http://myserver.com/foo.html
```

instead of ip address.

I do not like to change /etc/hosts since it is read only. it is not a good idea to change it.

How to use DNS to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Except editing /etc/hosts you have two options:

### Set up DNS server on Windows 10

[MaraDns](http://maradns.samiam.org/download.html) is a free open-source DNS server.

- You will need to map `myserver.com->192.168.137.1`
- All the other domain requests just pass to `8.8.8.8`
- Configure the windows 10 IP as the android DNS

### Set up DNS on your router

If you don't have this ability on your router you might try [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is a Linux based alternative OpenSource firmware suitable for a great variety of WLAN routers and embedded systems.

- Again, you will need to map `myserver.com->192.168.137.1`
- All the other domain requests just pass to `8.8.8.8`
- Configure the router IP as the android DNS